# Display prolog variable

Tags: prolog, chess

I need some help , I'm new with Prolog and I need to display a variable that I initialize , but I keep getting errors , can Anyone help me ? Here's the code :

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [member/2]).
:- use_module(contestlib, [for/3]).

knights(N,Max) :-
    PlacedKnights = [],
    findall((X,Y),(for(X,1,N),for(Y,1,N)),Squares),
    knights(Squares,PlacedKnights,Max).

knights(N,Max,PlacedKnights) :- 
    findall((X,Y),(for(X,1,N),for(Y,1,N)),Squares),
    knights(Squares,PlacedKnights,Max).
knights([],PlacedKnights,Max) :-
    # length(PlacedKnights,Max).
knights([(X,Y)|Squares],PlacedKnights,Max) :-
    ( is_attacked(X,Y,PlacedKnights) ->
        knights(Squares,PlacedKnights,Max)
    ;
        knights(Squares,[knight(X,Y)|PlacedKnights],Max1),
        knights(Squares,PlacedKnights,Max2),
        Max is max(Max1,Max2)
    ).

is_attacked(X,Y,PlacedKnights) :-
    ( NX is X - 1, NY is Y - 2
    ; NX is X - 1, NY is Y + 2
    ; NX is X + 1, NY is Y - 2
    ; NX is X + 1, NY is Y + 2
    ; NX is X - 2, NY is Y - 1
    ; NX is X - 2, NY is Y + 1
    ; NX is X + 2, NY is Y - 1
    ; NX is X + 2, NY is Y + 1
    ),
    member(knight(NX,NY),PlacedKnights).
```

I need to display the PlacedKnights at the end when knights clause if finished
I Tried this , but I get Error :

ERROR: =character' expected, found1,1'

```
 knights(N,Max,Display) :-
    PlacedKnights = [],
    findall((X,Y),(for(X,1,N),for(Y,1,N)),Squares),
    knights(Squares,PlacedKnights,Max), Display = PlacedKnights.
```

Comment: If you change `knights(N,Max)` to `knights(N,Max,Display)`, it will then have 3 arguments and be mixed up with the other `knights/3` clauses where the 3 arguments have a different meaning. You will need to change the name of either the main clause (*e.g.*, `show_knights(N,Max,Display)`) or change the name of the other clauses. As an aside, you don't need a new variable. You can just include `PlacedKnights` in the argument list: `show_knights(N,Max,PlacedKnights)`.

Comment: You should try solving some simpler problems in Prolog before jumping into that. From your code it's obvious that you think variables behave in a different way than they actually are in Prolog.